# When calling Calendar.getInstance(), gives a StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, stack-overflow

So I have been at this for 4 hours.  I have this project constructed on 3 different computers on the same emulators.  The other computers run this code perfectly fine without errors.  This computer constantly puts out this StackOverflowError shortly after interacting with the UI prompting a Calendar.getInstance() call.

This is what follows in the debugger after that line runs.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.coinc.coinc.coinc, PID: 3596
                  java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                      at sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getFixedDate(BaseCalendar.java:368)
                      at java.util.GregorianCalendar.getFixedDate(GregorianCalendar.java:3034)
                      at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2727)
                      at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3397)
                      at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1761)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.Functions.DaysBetweenTwoDates.getDays(DaysBetweenTwoDates.java:19)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:48)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.SubActivity.<init>(SubActivity.java:15)
                      at com.coinc.coinc.coinc.DataStructures.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:56)
```

Here is the code that creates this issue.  A call to this method on only my device creates the above error.

```
public static int getDays(Time t1, Time t2)
{
    Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(t1.getYear().getYear(), t1.getMonth().getMonthNumber(), t1.getDay().getDayInMonthNumber());
    Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(t2.getYear().getYear(), t2.getMonth().getMonthNumber(), t2.getDay().getDayInMonthNumber());
    long startLong = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
    long endLong = cal2.getTimeInMillis();
    long timeBetween = endLong - startLong;
    // System.out.println(endLong + " - " + startLong + " = " + timeBetween + " (" + timeBetween/86400000 + " days)");
    return (int)(timeBetween / 86400000);
}
```

Here is my current Emulator settings:

```
Name: Copy_of_Copy_of_Nexus_7_API_26

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\Cody\.android\avd\Copy_of_Copy_of_Nexus_7_API_26.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 26)

Skin: nexus_7_2013

SD Card: 100M

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 7 2013

vm.heapSize: 128

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.lcd.width: 1200

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: landscape

image.androidVersion.api: 26

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-26\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Copy_of_Copy_of_Nexus_7_API_26

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 320

avd.ini.displayname: Copy_of_Copy_of_Nexus_7_API_26

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:1a386603f0bf133098332c61cb3a4ee2

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: false

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: no

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the relevant code.

Comment: Can you also share details about host OS and image version?

Comment: is it Heap Size problem ?

Comment: Does this happen inside a recursive method? Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? I cannot readily reproduce.

Comment: @AliAhmed Can not rule it out, but the fact that it works on the SAME emulator on other computers... makes me believe it is something with my android studio settings or something similar local to only this computer.

Comment: @OleV.V.  As stated in the question, it ONLY happens on my computer when running on ANY emulator.  No other computer I have will have this error when I run it.  It is something local to this computer.

Comment: @OleV.V. To add on to my previous comment, I can also NOT replicate it on other compilers or other computers.  It is only this computer, and this one call to Calendar.getInstance() that creates the issue.  My program calls Calender.getInstance() in other parts of the program that do indeed work correctly without crashes/stack overflow.

Comment: Usually the problem behind StackOverflowErrors is not the method seen on top of stacktrace but something higher up in the call graph. Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @laalto Sure thing, editting it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in your stacktrace, your `SubActivity` is instantiating an `Activity` and `Activity` is instantiating a `SubActivity`. You need to fix this infinite ping-pong.

Part of `Activity` init is a call that goes 6 levels deeper in the call chain (to `Calendar` and so on), and eventually that is enough to overflow the stack.

Comment: Bravo sir!  It was indeed an issue within the constructor of each other.